# Install and skip unverified app message using Appium

Tags: java, android, mobile, automated-tests, appium

could you help me with a question? Currently I’m working in a project using react native and when I try to install this app using Appium, a message is shown indicating that there is some validation and it’s not possible to install unless it is from the official stores (App Store / Play Store).

[Unverified App Message - Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/az8No.png)

I’ve been trying to skip this message running the test scripts with some ‘adb’ commands like: adb install -i "com.android.example" but I believe that’s not the best approach.

I appreciate if someone can help me with that.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

If you will perform following steps manually or using script on android device. It will not show this message box.

1. Navigate to Setting > Security.
2. Check the option "Unknown sources".
3. Tap OK on the prompt message.
4. Select "Trust".